# Product images are not visible in mozilla but visible in chrome?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I set up an e-commerce website using Wordpress but can't see some of my product images in Mozilla Firefox but they are all visible in chrome. Why is this happening? Is it something to do with the images or browser?

Comment: 'm voting to close this question because Wordpress admin/support issues are off-topic as per the tag wiki

Answer (score 0):

First check the format of images you are using as a thumbnail because google chrome supports more image formats than Mozila. As troubleshooting instructions you should also check the version.

Note: Many site issues can be caused by corrupt cookies or cache.

Clear the Cache and Remove Cookies ( This will log you out of sites you're logged in to. ).